# Install imdb-api and use it in Angular2 Webpack

Tags: node.js, git, angular, webpack

I am trying to use the **imdb-api** repo **(https://github.com/worr/node-imdb-api)** in my angular2 project, but can't seem to get it working.

I'm working on the newest angular2 webpack [(Angular2 Webpack Starter)](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). I usually know how to get libs working, but this one is just not working :(

Have cloned the Angular2 Webpack starter, and made the Npm install and npm start.. everything works great.

Then I have installed version 2.0.0 of imdb-api like this:

```
npm install --save imdb-api
```

It installed with no problems.

In a component, (lets say the about component) , I have imported the module like:

```
import * as imdb from 'imdb-api';
```

In the constructor, I am trying to console.log(imdb) to see if it's available.

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // var imdb = require('imdb-api');
    console.log(imdb);
}
```

As you see, I also tried using the **var imdb = require ...**

The problem is all this gives me errors I just can't seem to solve. I am getting the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Mikkel\Documents\Programmering\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\request\lib'

ERROR in ./~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\Mikkel\Documents\Programmering\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\forever-agent'

ERROR in ./~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\Mikkel\Documents\Programmering\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\forever-agent'

ERROR in ./~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\Mikkel\Documents\Programmering\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'

ERROR in ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\Mikkel\Documents\Programmering\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\tunnel-agent'

ERROR in ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\Mikkel\Documents\Programmering\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
```

I have found a post about the request problem. The imdb-api is using the request-promise, thats why I'm getting the error.

The post you find here: https://github.com/request/request/issues/1529

The suggested to add the following:

```
console: 'empty',
fs: 'empty',
net: 'empty',
tls: 'empty'
```

to the node object in the webpack.config.js file. Have added it to the webpack dev config, but now I don't see any errors at all, but the application wont load.